# knockoutjs if statement and replace text with html

Tags: html, text, knockout.js, binding

what would be the best way to aproach this in knockoutjs?
I want to replace the data-bind="text: Order" with an image based on what is returned.  Examples of what ive tried are in the code below. First example works ok but just returns text (ASC or DESC). 2nd example just returns both. Third example works but I need to display the object as html. Thanks.

```
   <div class="col-md-3 sort-order">

                                    <!--<div class="col-md-3 sort-field" data-bind="text: Order"></div>-->

                                    <!-- ko if: Order() === 'ASC' -->
                                    <object data='~/Content/svg/plans/order-down.svg' type='image/svg+xml' />
                                    <!-- /ko -->
                                    <!-- ko if: Order() === 'DESC' -->
                                    <object data='~/Content/svg/plans/order-up.svg' type='image/svg+xml' />
                                    <!-- /ko -->
                                </div>


                                <!--<div class="col-md-3 sort-order" data-bind="text: (ko.unwrap(Order) == 'ASC') ?'<object data='~/Content/svg/plans/order-down.svg' type='image/svg+xml' />' : '<object data='~/Content/svg/plans/order-up.svg' type='image/svg+xml' />'">
                                    </div>-->
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code instead of using the text binding use like this:

```
data-bind="html:'your html part goes here'"
```